# Use AD credentials for GIT login

Tags: git, active-directory, credentials, gitlab

Is there a way to let git use my windows domain logon (AD) credentials for its authentifikation?

Problem is that you I'll have to change my credentials on a regular cycle because our gitLab server uses the same AD base. So I'll also have to update my git credentials within the cycle of my windows logon change cycle.

Could I use the git-credential-winstore to refer to my logon credentials or any other way of doing so?

Answer (score 0):

The actual method wouldn't need a [credential helper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18362082/6309) (like [git-credential-winstore](http://gitcredentialstore.codeplex.com/)).

It would use the [Kerberos protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_%28protocol%29): see "[Custom omniauth provider configurations / Working kerberos Configuration](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-public-wiki/wiki/Custom-omniauth-provider-configurations#wiki-working-kerberos-configuration)".
It isn't officially supported, but interest was there ([issue 3422](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/3422), but that interest hasn't surfaced in the [feedback forum](http://feedback.gitlab.com/forums/176466-general?query=kerberos)).

That way, any https GitLab repo url would benefit from the current Kerberos authentication ticket, for the transaction to benefit from your username/password (without you having to enter anything).

You can see [one post only (February 2014)](http://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/gitlabhq/kerberos/gitlabhq/X7Esv8jI9Os/miOgpue1cl0J) trying to implement that option, but with a few issues remaining.